# Auto flagging posts with specific tags

Tags: discussion, feature-request, migration

A good example is [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu): If you look at the questions, it's like 80% offtopic questions that should be moved to askubuntu.com, unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com.

Or at least there could be some warning before posting a question with such tags, telling the poster to reconsider posting the question to a more suitable stackexchange site.

EDIT:
Just to elaborate what is the problem. These questions usually get few close flags, but before they can get 5, they are just buried in the influx of new questions.

The ratio of off-topic vs. closed/migrated is the actual problem.

Comment: Only 369 questions out of 4,133 questions tagged [tag:ubuntu] are closed, or migrated.

Comment: @kiamlaluno And that is exactly the problem I'm talking about. 80% offtopic and only 9% closed or migrated.

Comment: I agree, but there's an unwritten "Do not move old stuff" rule. I don't like it, I challenge it, but it exists. Making SE a "repository of knowledge" doesn't seem like a valid argument anymore.

Comment: @problAm Yeah, but I'm more concerned about new incoming questions.

Comment: There are also questions that are using that tag when it is not necessary. I am not sure it is possible to say that a question should be probably asked on another site just basing on the tag being used.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I don't think that's the intended use here. The tag acts as a flag. The flag is reviewed by a human being, the human being makes the call.

Comment: @problAm I am referring to the first sentence of the question, where the OP is suggesting that those questions should be migrated. I could agree about the warning given to who is asking the question, if that would be in the form "Consider asking the question on [link to the site]." Auto flagging a question, which is then on-topic on the site where it is asked, simply basing on the tags doesn't seem so helpful.